# How do i go to previous state in AngularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs, search

I am building a search application. After the first search, when user goes for another search, I need to revert back to my base state and then re-populate the page based on the second search. How do i do this? Any actions to be attached to the "Search" button?

Comment: post some of code you tried.